# Problem connecting remotly to mysql on another computer

Tags: c#, sql, mysql

I want to connect remotely via c# to some other pc that has mysql on it.

I am getting following error `"Host 'dhycp-157-96.ist.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"`

On the server where i want to connect i gave needed privileges to my user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sa'@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

connection string looks like this:

```
string connStr = "server=" + host +
                             ";user="  + user +
                             ";port=3306" +
                             ";password=" + password +
                             ";";
```

Any idea what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO sa@localhost;
```

^^^ This grants access from **localhost** only, you need something more like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO sa@%;
```

This will grant access from any host.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should have been 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO sa@'dhycp-157-96.ist.com';

Answer (score 0):

You granted privileges to the user connecting from `localhost`, not from other machines.

Answer (score 0):

```
'sa'@localhost
```

This means "User 'sa' connecting from localhost".

Change localhost to the host you need to connect from.